# Viewing and managing remotely "another computer booting "

Tags: bios, remote-access, remote-control

Is there a way to view remotely an another computer booting since powered on until OS starts .

(For example ,be able to view the manufacturer logo , Bios and Boot menu Keys screen , Windows Starting .....)

Even be able to access BIOS if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using an [Intel vPro](http://www.intel.in/content/www/in/en/processors/vpro/core-processors-with-vpro-technology.html) processor, the Intel AMT KVM feature will help you out in remotely managing your IT infrastructure. [Check details here](http://www.howtogeek.com/56538/how-to-remotely-control-your-pc-even-when-it-crashes/).

A practical enterprise grade application for this purpose can be [RealVNC Viewer Plus](http://www.realvnc.com/products/viewerplus/). There are other applications available as well. I have just given an example.
You can check out [Radmin Viewer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7PrB5Rs3pE) as well.